# change area of tag "a" for click

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```
<div id="div1" style="width:200px;height:200px;" >
<a href="http://url.com" >some text </a>
</div>
```

according on the above code when user move mouse on "some text" he can click on the link.
but i want to change the above code when the user move mouse on the div area could click and go to the `"http://url.com"` .
I do not to use padding.

Comment: I would.. use padding that is. You could always apply `display:block` to your `a`, but you need the width and height on the `a` as well (even skip assigning to `div`). Inline styles can get really messy fast.

Comment: @jumpingcode I test that but this is not working.if I use padding other style change in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make the `a` tag a block level element you will be able to make the entire area clickable.

Here is the css:

```
#div1 a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V8Tx4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you can wrap links around block-level elements.

```
<a href="http://url.com" >
    <div id="div1" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
        some text
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: don't use block elements inside inline elements, meaning don't put a <div> inside a <a>

Comment: It's [valid HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/) and thus a proper answer.

Comment: @LarsBeck `HTML5` is not the only form of `HTML` and thus is not a proper answer in every aspect.

Comment: I understand but did the OP specify he wanted it in `HTML5`? I'm also not down-voting because it is a possible answer but not 100% solid.

Comment: It's not a proper answer in terms of HTML per se but a proper answer relative to HTML5, furthermore the OP didn't specify any HTML version at all. ;)

Comment: This is true, but he also didn't include the `HTML5` tag. ;}.

Comment: I think the whole semantically wrong argument is stupid at this point. I mean, we are in a constant state of flux with browser implementations, and standards, and interpretations of standards, and hacks to work in various browsers...I mean, I've been doing this for years, and damn it, if it works, use it.

Answer (score 0):

place the `<a>` outside the div or use block style in the `<a>`

```
<a href="http://url.com">
   <div id="div1" style="width:200px;height:200px;">some text
   </div> 
</a>
```

or...

```
<a href="http://url.com" style='display:block;height:200px;width:200px'>some text</a>
```